# AEM 6.5, creating bulk pages using Groovy script

Tags: groovy, aem, aem-6

Is it possible to create pages in a folder in bulk with 2 values added to the page properties using Groovy script?

I have a CSV file with, page title, page redirect path.
Looking for a script that would go in and create X number pages using the page title, redirect path in a specific folder.

Thank you

Comment: Please add the code you have tried and how it failed (e.g. errors,
stacktraces, logs, ...) so we can improve on it.

Comment: Of course it should be possible to do it in Groovy (PageManger.create, Page.getContentResource, ...). BUT if you wanna do mass-redirects, I strongly recommend to do this on the Apache (aka Dispatcher). The redirects in AEM are good for content-editors to create a few manually (without access to the dispatcher). Something like a SEO-conform site migration with some 10.000 redirects are even challenging for an Apache webserver.